Flask flasgger Swagger validation not working
I don't seem to be able to make swag_from work as intended.
This is my API
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flasgger import swag_from, Swagger

app = Flask(__name__)
swagger = Swagger(app)

@app.post('/calculate')
@swag_from('calculate.yml', validation=True)
def calculate() -> Flask.response_class:
    request_data = request.get_json()
    flights = request_data['flights']
    if not isinstance(flights, collections.Iterable):
        return jsonify({ 'message': 'Invalid input, should be a valid list' }), 400 
    return jsonify({ 'result': 'something here' }), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

and this is my .yml
...etc etc
paths:
  /calculate:
    post:
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: request
          description: request
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/GetFlightPath'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/GetFlightResponse'
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
      deprecated: false
definitions:
  GetFlightResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      description:
        type:
          string
      cost:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Cost'
    title: GetFlight response
  GetFlightPath:
    type: object
    properties:
      flights:
        type: array
        items:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
    title: GetFlight Request

When I POST to e.g. "http://127.0.0.1:8080/calculate"
{
    "flights": [["SFO", 1]]
}

I would expect the validation to fail. I reckon this is the intended behaviour, the schema from the "in: body" parameter is used to validate the request.
What am I doing wrong?

alright, 25 seconds after posting this I figured it out... I was using a yaml schema instead of yml. My bad

tags:
  - Calculate Flights
parameters:
  - in: body
    name: request
    description: request
    required: true
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/GetFlightPath'
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
    schema:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/definitions/GetFlightResponse'
  '400':
    description: Bad Request
  '401':
    description: Unauthorized
definitions:
  GetFlightResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      description:
        type:
          string
      cost:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Cost'
    title: GetFlight response
  GetFlightPath:
    type: object
    properties:
      flights:
        type: array
        items:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
    title: GetFlight Request

